# だお (net slang?)

Tags: sentence-final-particles, internet-slang

I think I remember some characters in steins;gate ending sentences with お or だお. What does it mean?

Comment: Do you have any example sentences? (Please?)

Comment: I don't have any examples now, but I can look for some when I get home. I mostly remember this expression being used by Daru.

Comment: 「～だよ」が「～だお」になったんだと思うお。最近あまり見なくなったお。 http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%8A

Comment: It sounds like he says ｢実はさ、ラボに財布忘れてきたお」 in this video, around 3:27 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0eq1TxBKME

Comment: You might find this interesting: http://beauty.oricon.co.jp/trend-culture/trend/news/2051385/full/　The term is definitely a turn-off for many women.

Comment: 確かに、「ラボに財布忘れてきたお」って言ってますね。あ、じゃなくて、言ってるお。

Comment: 個人的には「だよ」由来説には疑問で、むしろ一人ツッコミの「…（お」のある種の誤読由来だと思われ。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that it came from `～だよ`.

This is just my opinion but by using `～だお` instead of `～だよ` for a character, you can make him/her sound like a person who is cute, laid back, easy-going, girly, ほんわか、萌え系、のんびり、..., etc.

I think that these characters often don't speak clearly or speak like a little boy/girl just to create the characteristics listed above so `y` is dropped in `dayo` and it sounds like `dao`.